# C++/Win. Not getting FD_CLOSE

Tags: windows, winapi, sockets

I have an asynchronous socket and call to connect() + GetLastError() which returns WSA_WOULD_BLOCK, as expected. So I start "receiving/reading" thread and subscribe Event to FD_READ and FD_CLOSE.

The story is: connect will sequentially fail, since Server is not up and running. My understanding that my receiving thread should get FD_CLOSE soon and I need to follow-up with cleaning.

It does not happen. How soon should I receive FD_CLOSE? Is it proper approach? Is there any other way to understand that connect() failed? Shoul I ever receive FD_CLOSE if socket isn't connected?

I do start my receiving thread and subscribe event after successful call to DoConnect() and I am afraid that racing condition prevents me from getting FD_CLOSE.

Here is some code:

```
int RecvSocketThread::WaitForData()
{
     int retVal = 0
     while (!retVal)
     {
         // sockets to pool can be added on other threads.
         // please validate that all of them in the pool are connected
         // before doing any reading on them
         retVal = DoWaitForData();
     }
}

int RecvSocketThread::DoWaitForData()
{
    // before waiting for incoming data, check if all sockets are connected
    WaitForPendingConnection_DoForAllSocketsInThePool();


    // other routine to read (FD_READ) or react to FD_CLOSE
    // create array of event (each per socket) and wait
}
void RecvSocketThread::WaitForPendingConnection_DoForAllSocketsInThePool()
{
    // create array and set it for events associated with pending connect sockets
    HANDLE* EventArray = NULL;
    int counter = 0;
    EventArray = new HANDLE[m_RecvSocketInfoPool.size()];

    // add those event whose associated socket is still not connected
    // and wait for FD_WRITE and FD_CLOSE. At the end of this function
    // don't forget to switch them to FD_READ and FD_CLOSE
    while (it != m_RecvSocketInfoPool.end())
    {
         RecvSocketInfo* recvSocketInfo = it->second;
         if (!IsEventSet(recvSocketInfo->m_Connected, &retVal2))
         {
             ::WSAEventSelect(recvSocketInfo->m_WorkerSocket, recvSocketInfo->m_Event, FD_WRITE | FD_CLOSE);
             EventArray[counter++] = recvSocketInfo->m_Event;
         }
         ++it;
    }
    if (counter)
    {
        DWORD indexSignaled = WaitForMultipleObjects(counter, EventArray, WaitAtLeastOneEvent, INFINITE);

        // no matter what is further Wait doen't return for failed to connect socket

        if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 <= indexSignaled &&
                   indexSignaled < (WAIT_OBJECT_0 + counter))
        {
            it = m_RecvSocketInfoPool.begin();
            while (it != m_RecvSocketInfoPool.end())
            {
                RecvSocketInfo* recvSocketInfo = it->second;
                if (IsEventSet(recvSocketInfo->m_Event, NULL))
                {
                  rc = WSAEnumNetworkEvents(recvSocketInfo->m_WorkerSocket,
                  recvSocketInfo->m_Event, &networkEvents);

                   // Check recvSocketInfo->m_Event using WSAEnumnetworkevents
                   // for FD_CLOSE using FD_CLOSE_BIT
                   if ((networkEvents.lNetworkEvents & FD_CLOSE))
                   {
                       recvSocketInfo->m_FD_CLOSE_Recieved = 1;
                       *retVal = networkEvents.iErrorCode[FD_CLOSE_BIT];
                   }
                   if ((networkEvents.lNetworkEvents & FD_WRITE))
                   {
                       WSASetEvent(recvSocketInfo->m_Connected);
                       *retVal = networkEvents.iErrorCode[FD_WRITE_BIT];
                   }
                }
                ++it;
            }
        }

        // if error - DoClean, if FD_WRITE (socket is writable) check if m_Connected
        // before do any sending
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you monitoring for connect() completion?  ie. which WinSock API, and what params do you use to wait for it to be done?

Comment: I am not monitoring it. DoConnect() is my non-blocking function which creates socket, turn-it to non-blocking and call connect. I understand that connection is still pending. I need a way to understand that connection finally has not been established. It's winsock 1.1.

Comment: One important thing here is how does `m_connected` get set? Can you include that logic in your code posted?

Comment: Updated. It is doesn't matter since WaitForMUltipleobjects never returns

Comment: Sorry dude, I give up here.  I don't see any sign that you are getting the suggestions that are being made.  If you know why the code is failing why did you post the question? If you don't know, how can you possibly say what matters or not?

Comment: Now, I'm changing the code to react to FD_CONNECT. Thanks to you! I just realized that everything was right and I will never receive FD_CLOSE in this sitaution. It's not proper event here. It takes time to understand how to change the code, you know... I've posted the answer with idea how to do it correctly.

Comment: I know this is difficult, but I think (based on what you have said) that picking up `FD_CONNECT` will make this soluble for you

Answer (score 2):

You will not receive an `FD_CLOSE` notification if `connect()` fails.  You must subscribe to `FD_CONNECT` to detect that.  This is clearly stated in the [connect() documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625.aspx):

> With a nonblocking socket, the connection attempt cannot be completed
>   immediately. In this case, connect will return SOCKET_ERROR, and
>   WSAGetLastError will return WSAEWOULDBLOCK. In this case, there are
>   three possible scenarios:
>
> •Use the select function to determine the completion of the
>   connection request by checking to see if the socket is writeable.
>
> **•If the application is using WSAAsyncSelect to indicate interest in
>   connection events, then the application will receive an FD_CONNECT
>   notification indicating that the connect operation is complete
>   (successfully or not).**
>
> •If the application is using WSAEventSelect to indicate interest in
>   connection events, then the associated event object will be signaled
>   indicating that the connect operation is complete (successfully or
>   not).

The result code of `connect()` will be in the event's `HIWORD(lParam)` value when `LOWORD(lParam)` is `FD_CONNECT`.  If the result code is 0, `connect()` was successful, otherwise it will be a WinSock error code.

Comment: Thanks. Probably FD_CONNECT is only way to get it. I'll try to change code and start/prepare thread to wait for FD_CONNECT. It's a bit complicated to make a test right away, since there are other BalanceLoading logic in the code.

Comment: Either don't start your receiving thread at all unless `FD_CONNECT` reports success, or else just update the receive thread to include `FD_CONNECT`.  It just won't get `FD_READ` or `FD_CLOSE` unless it gets a successful `FD_CONNECT` first, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `connect()` and get a blocking notification you have to write more code to monitor for `connect()` completion (success or failure) via one of three methods as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> With a nonblocking socket, the connection attempt cannot be completed
> immediately. In this case, connect will return SOCKET_ERROR, and
> WSAGetLastError will return WSAEWOULDBLOCK. In this case, there are
> three possible scenarios:
>
> •Use the select function to determine the completion of the connection
> request by checking to see if the socket is writeable.
>
> •If the
> application is using WSAAsyncSelect to indicate interest in connection
> events, then the application will receive an FD_CONNECT notification
> indicating that the connect operation is complete (successfully or
> not).
>
> •If the application is using WSAEventSelect to indicate interest
> in connection events, then the associated event object will be
> signaled indicating that the connect operation is complete
> (successfully or not).

Comment: I know about FD_WRITE, but I can't wait for FD_WRITE since receiving thread already subscribed to FD_READ and FD_CLOSE. Two events cannot be attached to state of a single socket.

Comment: Again, which API are you using here in the 'receiving thread'?

Comment: I know. What Win32 function (API) does your receiving thread call to check for events on the socket?

Comment: ::WSAEventSelect((SOCKET)m_WorkerSocket, m_Event, FD_READ|FD_CLOSE);

Comment: I have about 50 sockets per thread. So I have 50 events (per each socket)

Comment: You are missing the `connect()` result. Use `FD_READ|FD_CLOSE|FD_WRITE`, if the `connect()` works you can remask using what you have now. You will not see `FD_CLOSE` if the socket never `connect()`s OK. See comments re `FD_WRITE` here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741576(v=vs.85).aspx, and use `WsaEnumNetworkEvents` to work out what events happened.

Comment: Sending thread waiting for m_Connected event to be reaised. Receiving thread before it start looping and waiting for FD_READ and FD_CLOSE, on it's thread checks for FD_WRITE and as soon as it's writable sets m_Connected event.

Comment: Still question. Will I ever receive FD_CLOSE if connect failed? Is FD_CLOSE message serialized and I can check for FD_CLOSE mili-seconds after it failed. My receiving thread will probably set event to check writability too late. If I never get FD_CLOSE what else should I check for?

Comment: For what event? You just said I will never get FD_CLOSE

Comment: Why don't you post the code that handles connect failure and we can get more specific?

Comment: Ok, later today. There so many code, so I need to cut it a bit first.

Answer (score 0):

I think I need to start Receving thread once socket handle is created, but before connect is called. It is too late to create it after connect was called on asynchronous socket.
For synchronous socket those two calls createsocket() and connect() was just two consequitive lines. Does not work for non-blocking.

In this case at the beginning of receiving thread I need to check for FD_CONNECT and/or FD_WRITE in order be informed of connect attempt status.

Comment: Ok. Here is an update. I have changed the code and before any reading on client side I check for FD_CONNECT status. If connected I set m_Connected, if failed - set m_FailedSocket event. Sending thread checks for status of those two events before any attempt to send(). On server side, once socket is accepted, I explicitly set m_Connected and socket ready for FD_READ and FD_CLOSE.